# Array filtration of String with contains is slow

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, contains

searching text from an array of Product, but data is huge, and stuck ui view and keyboard.

```
func searchText(text: String) -> [Product]{

        self.filterData = text.isEmpty ? self.productCollection : self.productCollection.filter({(product: Product) -> Bool in
            // If dataItem matches the searchText, return true to include it

            if product.item_title?.range(of: text, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil {
                return true
            }
            else if String(product.item_id).range(of: text, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil {
                return true
            }
            return product.team_options.contains(where: { (option : Product) -> Bool in
                if option.item_title?.range(of: text, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil {
                    return true
                }
                return option.team_options.contains(where: { (option : Product) -> Bool in
                    return option.item_title?.range(of: text, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
                })
            })

        })

  return self.filterData

}
```

This is searchbar function

```
   func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) { 
     DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        self.filterData = self.searchText(text: searchText)
    }


        (self.view as? ScannerView)?.setData(data: self.filterData)
  }
```

any other way for searching String from an array please help.

Comment: make your search in background thread and update UI when you have a result to show

Comment: Use this -> `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {}`

Comment: no major difference, but a little bit

Comment: You are performing the search asynchronously but updating the UI before the asynchronous operation is complete. You need to dispatch the UI update on the main queue inside the closure where you call `searchText`

Comment: What @Paulw11 said should be the accepted answer: you're updating your UI in the wrong places.